# Newforms are eigenforms for the diamond operators

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Let $S_k(\Gamma_1(N))^{\textrm{new}}$ denote the new subspace of the space of weight $k$ cusp forms on $\Gamma_1(N)$. Section 5.8 of Diamond and Shurman's modular forms book is supposed to show that if $f \in S_k(\Gamma_1(N))^{\textrm{new}}$, then $f$ is an eigenform for all of the Hecke operators $T_n$ and diamond operators $\left<n\right>$. It seems to me there is a gap though, as the first paragraph of the section ends by noting that it is clear that $f$ is an eigenform for $\left<n\right>$ if $\gcd(n,N) > 1$. since in this case  $\left<n\right>$ is the zero operator. Then it says, "Thus the only operators in question are the $T_n$." Well, no... The operators $\left<n\right>$ for $\gcd(n,N) = 1$ are never addressed. In fact  it seems to me that then the entire new subspace must be contained in a single $\chi$-eigenspace $S_k(N,\chi)$ for some Dirichlet character $\chi$ modulo $N$, since these eigenspaces are linearly disjoint.

Comment: $\langle d\rangle$ commutes with the $T_n,\gcd(n,N)=1$ thus the eigenforms are eigenfunctions of $\langle d\rangle$ (which proves $f$ is in $\Gamma_0(N),\chi$ where $\chi(d) f= \langle d\rangle f$).

Comment: @reuns The line I quoted in the book was stated before they proved that $f$ is an eigenform for the $T_n$. So is there a way to see this without knowing it's an eigenform for the $T_n$?

Comment: See the proofs that $T_n$ sends $M_k(\Gamma_0(N),\chi)$ to itself to obtain that on each $M_k(\Gamma_0(N),\chi)$ thus on $M_k(\Gamma_1(N))$, $\langle d\rangle T_n=T_n \langle d\rangle$